# Sending html text in an email

Tags: android

I'd like users to be able to send emails from my app and the client would like the message body to be html-formatted.  They look nicer and the message includes a rather ugly url that would be better placed inside an anchor tag.

I've seen some older queries on the web asking how to do this but have not been able to find a definitive answer.

Is it possible to use an Intent.ACTION_SEND (or some other method) to send an email pre-set with an html-formatted message body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, take a look at this post: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/

You would then just change line 52 from `text/plain` to `text/html`.

Comment: Actually, this solution seems to require a gmail account.  Probably not going to meet client requirements.

Comment: Not necessarily, just adjust the STMP server settings (mailhost, username, password) to whatever your user enters or whatever SMTP server you'd like to use. This is just plain vanilla STMP communication.